# showing that $x_{y(i)_2} = i$ for all square free $i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Define a sequence $x_n$ as follows. Let $x_0 = 1$, $A(k)$ be the product of all prime numbers less than $p(k)$, where $p(k)$ is the smallest prime number that does not divide $k$ and let $x_{n+1}$ satisfy $x_{n+1} A(x_n) = x_n p(x_n)$. Prove that for all square-free positive integers $i$, $x_{y(i)_2} = i$, where $y(i)$ is defined so that if $i = p_{a_1}\cdots p_{a_k}$ and $p_j$ is the $j$th prime (the first is $2$, then $3$, etc.), then $y(i) = b_{a_k}\cdots b_{1}$ where $b_j = \begin{cases}1,&\text{ if $j=a_l$ for some $1\leq l\leq k$}\\
> 0,&\text { otherwise }\end{cases}$. Also, prove that all the $x_i$'s are distinct, so that $y(i)_2$ is the smallest $k$ so that $x_k=i$ for any square free $i$.

I know that the $x_i$'s only include distinct primes, and this can be shown by induction and using the definition of the $A(x_n)$'s. Indeed, the base case is trivial and assuming this holds for $x_n$, it also holds for $x_{n+1}$ because if $p$ is any prime and $p | x_n$, then $p \not | p(x_n)$.

By induction, one can show that for all $0\leq n\leq 2^{a-1}-1$, we have $x_{n+2^{a-1}} = x_n \cdot p_a,$ where $p_a$ is the $a$th prime. It holds for $a=0,1$, and assuming it holds for all $a < k,k\ge 2$, we have $x_{1} = p_1, x_{1+2} = p_2 p_1, \cdots, x_{1+2+\cdots + 2^{a-2}} = x_{2^{a-1}-1} = \prod_{j=1}^{a-1} p_j$. Also, $x_{2^{a-1}} = p_a$, after which the $x_n$'s cycle for $2^a$ terms so that the relation $x_{2^{a-1} + n} = p_a x_n$ for $0\leq n\leq 2^{a-1}-1$ holds until we obtain $x_{2^{a}} = p_{a+1}$ and the cycle repeats.

> I think these claims might be useful for showing that the $x_n$'s are distinct, but I'm not sure how to show this.